# Filling values based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes as shown below. I'd like to create `non_promo_price` and `price` columns in `sales_df`. If the `week` and `year` values for a row in `sales_df` lie between the `start_week`, `start_year` and `end_week`, `end_year` in `promo_df`, the `non_promo_price` and `price` values in `promo_df` need to mapped to `sales_df`. The values need to be 0 if there is no week corresponding to it in `promo_df`.

```
sales_df.head()
```

| S.no | ppg | year | week | value_ty | unit_ty | price/unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 1 | 8963.05 | 1631 | 5.50 |
| 1 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 9 | 29205.14 | 4434 | 6.59 |
| 2 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 10 | 30062.83 | 4561 | 6.59 |
| 3 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 11 | 22691.00 | 3443 | 6.59 |
| 4 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 12 | 29381.84 | 4463 | 6.58 |
| 5 | Downy Perfume_Refill_490-580ml | 2021 | 22 | 48742.50 | 9945 | 4.90 |

`promo_df.head()`

| sno. | ppg | non_promo_price | price | start_year | start_week | end_year | end_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 6.20 | 5.28 | 2018 | 2 | 2018 | 4 |
| 1 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 6.20 | 5.29 | 2018 | 7 | 2018 | 9 |
| 2 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 5.99 | 5.49 | 2018 | 20 | 2018 | 22 |
| 3 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 5.99 | 5.09 | 2018 | 25 | 2018 | 27 |
| 4 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 6.65 | 5.48 | 2019 | 1 | 2019 | 3 |
| 5 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 6.65 | 5.29 | 2019 | 12 | 2019 | 14 |

I tried a left join on `sales_df` but it was giving me null values for `non_promo_price` and `price` for weeks that have no data in `promo_df`.

`pd.merge(sales_df, promo_df, left_on=["ppg", "year", "week"], right_on=["ppg", "start_year", "start_week"], how="left",)`

| S no. | ppg | year | week | value_ty | unit_ty | price/unit | non_promo_price | price | start_year | start_week | end_year | end_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 1 | 8963.05 | 1631 | 5.50 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 9 | 29205.14 | 4434 | 6.59 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | Daia_Refill_1.8liter | 2018 | 10 | 30062.83 | 4561 | 6.59 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_df = sales_df.merge(promo_df, how='left')
temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df.week.between(temp_df.start_week, temp_df.end_week)) & (temp_df.year.between(temp_df.start_year, temp_df.end_year))]
print(temp_df)
```

Output:

```
                     ppg  year  week  value_ty  unit_ty  price/unit  non_promo_price  price  start_year  start_week  end_year  end_week
7   Daia_Refill_1.8liter  2018     9  29205.14     4434        6.59             6.20   5.29      2018.0         7.0    2018.0       9.0
```

Comment: You'd only end up with one match if you follow what the OP asked for

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover Care to elaborate?

Comment: " If the week and year values for a row in sales_df lie between the start_week, start_year and end_week, end_year in promo_df"

Comment: Good point, does that change address the issue?